# Strong convexity

Tags: geometry, convex-optimization

I have to prove to things about strong convexity and I want to know if my demonstrations are corrects:

1: All of it in $R^n$.I have $f(x)$ strongly convex in $R^n$ and $g(x)=x-w$ with $w$ different from $0$. Then $f \circ g$ is strongly convex.

2:I have $f(x)$ strongly convex in $R^n$ and $g(x)=Ax-w$ where $g(x)$ belong to $R^m$, the matrix $A$ is $n\times m$ and different from $0$, and $w$ belongs to $R^n$.Then $f\circ g$ is strong convexity.

Prove:

1- I thought that when I do $f \circ g$ what I´m doing is a translation, and geometric properties of $f$ will not change with it. So $f \circ g$ is strongly convex like $f$.

2- I use the idea that $f \circ g$ can be a rotation if I take $w=0$ and $A$ like the matrix rotation. So if I take $A$ like the matrix rotation that rotates $f$ through $180$ degrees I can said it would not be a convex function and then will not be strongly convex.

If some explanation is not so clear just tell me and I will try to solve it.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument for (2) is not correct. If $g$ is a rotation and $f$ (strongly) convex then $f \circ g$ *is* (strongly) convex as well.

Generally, $g(x) = Ax + w$ with $A \in \Bbb R^{n\times m}$ and $w \in \Bbb R^n$ is an [*affine transformation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) from $ \Bbb R^m$ to $ \Bbb R^n$. In particular,
$$
 g(\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y) = \lambda g(x)+ (1-\lambda) g(y)
$$
for $x, y \in \Bbb R^m$ and $0 < \lambda < 1$. Therefore, if $f : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ is convex then
$$
 f(g(\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y)) = f( \lambda g(x)+ (1-\lambda) g(y)) \\
\le  \lambda f(g(x))+ (1-\lambda) f(g(y))
$$
which shows that $f \circ g$ is convex as well.

If $f$ is strongly convex and $A$ has full column rank then $f \circ g$ is strongly convex as well: $g$ is injective, so that $x \ne y$ implies 
$g(x) \ne g(y)$, and therefore 
$$
 f(g(\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y)) = f( \lambda g(x)+ (1-\lambda) g(y)) \\
<  \lambda f(g(x))+ (1-\lambda) f(g(y))
$$
for $x \ne y \in \Bbb R^m$ and $0 < \lambda < 1$.

Comment: I understand, thanks and I will try to follow all the steps of your prove. And about my first argument?

Comment: @Meliodas: Your conclusion in (1) is current, but I would not call *"what I'm doing is a translation, and geometric properties of f will not change"* a strict proof. Note also that (1) is a special  case of (2).

Comment: thanks, yes is not a very strict prove. I wanted to prove it without the calcul but I understand is better if I do all the calculus work.